# Drilling holes for security cameras

Tags: cable-management

I purchased an 8-channel DVR camera system and am STRUGGLING to figure out how to insert the cables into the wall to run it to the attic.

I understand that I need to run the cable up the wall, into the attic, and out the exterior. But my biggest confusion is, how many holes do I drill in my office wall at the source? This is an 8-channel DVR system with BNC cables. The cables have TWO ports each, so if I drill one hole, it would have to be a MASSIVE hole in my wall. If I drill 8 small holes, it will look disgusting.

Every video and article I've read does not cover this aspect. Is there a junction box of some sort that I can install in the wall so I can send my 8 cables with 16 ports through the wall and have it look neat?

Update:
I am not sure if this goes against the rules of this forum, [but here is the link to the camera system I purchased](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FR7TLXV). Maybe I am using the wrong words here to describe my camera system, so I wanted to add that here.

Comment: *DVR system with BNC* That's a bit surprising. Most systems now use twisted pair, typically Ethernet with PPOE so that you just run a single small cable and patch it to standard jacks and not have to deal with coax or power.

Comment: You can pass the connectors through the hole one at a time.  The hole needs to be big enough for seven of the eight cables, and then the larger of the two plugs to pass through.    I don't think that's such a big hole.  Can you describe what you mean by "MASSIVE"?   A 1-inch or maybe 1.5 inch hole might do?  And you can use a plastic grommet to tidy it up.  A patch panel for 16 connectors will look a lot worse.  Unless you go all-out data center decor.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact added a link to the camera I purchased, I might have used the wrong terms describing the system!

Comment: Just drilling a hole in the wall and passing cables though is ugly.  That is why there are covers/grommets/escutcheons to make stuff look neater.

Comment: @jay613 So I installed the exact same system, but a 4 camera system instead in my aunt's house and since EACH of these cables have 2 ports, after inserting the first 2 cables, the 3rd cable's ports HARDLY FIT in a 1 inch hole. Even if inserting the ports one by one, it was not very easy!

Comment: A 1.5 inch hole has 2.25 times the capacity of a 1 inch hole.  A 2 inch hole has 4 times the capacity. There is an answer already that I think you should let yourself be guided by! :)

Comment: I've installed some Swann stuff before (around 10 years ago). Decent, but I didn't like the cabling then and I really don't like it now given the PPOE-based alternatives, which were not as readily available (at a reasonable price) 10 years ago.

Comment: @jay613 Yup, the hole needs to be bigger was a given to me already but the cover terminology was where I was lost. I am going with a 2 or even a 3" hole and using one of those brush cover thingies!

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact PoE?  I'm using wifi and a low voltage DC cable to the nearest power outlet for cameras.  It's called "lazy".  If I'm going to run cable I'd rather add a mesh node than run it for one camera.   And to those who say WiFi is insecure ... if someone is going to hack in to my Wifi cameras in order to more successfully break into my house, I'd really really really like to know where the loot is to make that worthwhile.

Comment: @jay613 With reasonably well set up WiFi, security (for a normal building) is a non-issue. But *reliability* of getting a high-bandwidth signal (and one for each camera) through all the time can be a big issue.

Comment: [BNC connector wall plates](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bnc+connector+wall+plate&iax=images&ia=images)

Comment: @jsotola THAT IS AWESOME! Thank you very much! I am not very familiar with these cables, but I believe that there are TWO connectors on each end of each cable: one for the power and the other for the video feed. MOST of the results are just the video feed connector, not the power. [I found this one](https://www.amazon.com/White-Triple-Plate-2-1mm-Certicable/dp/B015WQBP8W) but it is WAY TOO EXPENSIVE. Any ideas for ones that have both video AND power?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact yeah, I think my recommendation would be to return this Swann system and buy a PoE one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would drill one hole and then use an escutcheon/wall grommet to hide the ugly. I would expect a 1-1/2" to 2" hole would work fine. One larger hole is much easier to deal with than eight.

Comment: I see some GREAT 2" and bigger wall grommets on Google. This is exactly the term I was looking for, "escutcheon/wall grommet". Thank you very much!

Comment: select the "answer accepted" in the voting panel to the left of the answer to indicate that you found this answer to be the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I went with a massive hole on the wall. I covered the outside wall with a junction box similar to this. Use silicone sealant between the wall and the box to prevent moisture.

[image]

Comment: Did you put your system DVR outdoors?   Why did you need a large hole to the outside?

Comment: My attic is not big enough for anyone to crawl in. So, I ran the cables on the outside wall, about 12 feet from the ground. They go into my DVR in a cabinet in my laundry room. Yes, It's ugly, but it works. My wall is also drywall/vinyl siding, so it's easy to drill.